# JScrollPane wont go into a JPanel with gridbag

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

my JScroll pane contains a Jlist, and is parented by a JPanel that has the gridbag layour, but it doesn't want to fit right it ends up really small and acts like its gridx is -1 and y is zero, when it should have a x of 0 and y of 1

code:

```
public class StartGui 
{
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private static JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
private static DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
private static JList<String> Targets = new JList<String>(listModel);
private static JButton Start = new JButton("Start");
private static JButton Stop = new JButton("Stop");
private static JButton Configure = new JButton("Configure");
private static JButton AddRecipiants = new JButton("Add Recipiants");
private static JProgressBar Progress = new JProgressBar();
private static JLabel RLable = new JLabel("Recipiants:");

private static JScrollPane lsp;

private static GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
private static GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

private static JFrame emails = new JFrame();
private static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
private static JTextArea emailA = new JTextArea("type email here");
private static JButton done = new JButton("OK");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 400);
    panel.setLayout(gbl);

    listModel.addElement("TestEmailAddress@fake.com");
    lsp = new JScrollPane(Targets);

    emails.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    emails.setResizable(false);
    emails.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 300);
    panel2.setLayout(gbl);
    emails.add(panel2);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 17;
    gbc.gridwidth = 20;
    gbc.gridheight = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5,70,5,70);
    gbl.setConstraints(done, gbc);
    panel2.add(done);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 20;
    gbc.gridheight = 17;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,10);
    gbl.setConstraints(emailA, gbc);
    panel2.add(emailA);

    emails.add(panel2);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 10;
    gbc.gridheight = 19;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    gbl.setConstraints(Targets, gbc);
    panel.add(lsp);

    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 11;
    gbc.gridwidth = 5;
    gbc.gridheight = 5;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(25,5,25,5);
    gbl.setConstraints(Start, gbc);
    panel.add(Start);

    gbc.gridx = 15;
    gbc.gridy = 11;
    gbc.gridwidth = 5;
    gbc.gridheight = 5;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(25,5,25,5);
    gbl.setConstraints(Stop, gbc);
    panel.add(Stop);

    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    gbc.gridwidth = 10;
    gbc.gridheight = 7;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(35,5,40,5);
    gbl.setConstraints(Configure, gbc);
    panel.add(Configure);

    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 10;
    gbc.gridheight = 4;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(25,5,20,5);
    gbl.setConstraints(AddRecipiants, gbc);
    panel.add(AddRecipiants);

    Progress.setMaximum(100);
    Progress.setString("0%");
    Progress.setValue(0);
    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 16;
    gbc.gridwidth = 10;
    gbc.gridheight = 4;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(25,5,15,5);
    gbl.setConstraints(Progress, gbc);
    panel.add(Progress);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 10;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5,45,0,45);
    gbl.setConstraints(RLable, gbc);
    panel.add(RLable);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `JScrollPane` preferred size isn't typically very large, and is generally determine from the `Scrollable` interface (and other factors)

You can affect the `JList`'s default size using the following methods...

- [`JList#setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29)
- [`JList#setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29)

The first will effect the number of rows that are visible in the view port and the second will effect the height and width of that row.

You are also NOT passing in constraints to the layout manager for the scroll pane (you are trying to use the `JList`) which isn't going to work...

You should be doing this...

```
panel.add(lsp, gbc);
```

And I would greatly discourage this...

```
gbl.setConstraints(Targets, gbc);
```

*(I should add, I would discourage the above generally, and recommend using `add(Component, Object)` - But that's me)*

**Updated**

My suggestions, vs your default code...

[image]

```
public class BadLayout10 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BadLayout10();
  }

  public BadLayout10() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        new StartGui();
      }
    });
  }

  public class StartGui {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    private JList<String> Targets = new JList<String>(listModel);
    private JButton Start = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton Stop = new JButton("Stop");
    private JButton Configure = new JButton("Configure");
    private JButton AddRecipiants = new JButton("Add Recipiants");
    private JProgressBar Progress = new JProgressBar();
    private JLabel RLable = new JLabel("Recipiants:");
    private JScrollPane lsp;
    private GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JFrame emails = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea emailA = new JTextArea("type email here");
    private JButton done = new JButton("OK");

    public StartGui() {

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 400);
      panel.setLayout(gbl);

      listModel.addElement("TestEmailAddress@fake.com");
      Targets.setVisibleRowCount(10);
      Targets.setPrototypeCellValue("This is a really long test string");
      lsp = new JScrollPane(Targets);

      emails.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      emails.setResizable(false);
      emails.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 300);
      panel2.setLayout(gbl);
      emails.add(panel2);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 17;
      gbc.gridwidth = 20;
      gbc.gridheight = 3;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 0;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 70, 5, 70);
      gbl.setConstraints(done, gbc);
      panel2.add(done);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.gridwidth = 20;
      gbc.gridheight = 17;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
      gbl.setConstraints(emailA, gbc);
      panel2.add(emailA);

      emails.add(panel2);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 1;
      gbc.gridwidth = 10;
      gbc.gridheight = 19;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
//      gbl.setConstraints(Targets, gbc);
      panel.add(lsp, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 10;
      gbc.gridy = 11;
      gbc.gridwidth = 5;
      gbc.gridheight = 5;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(25, 5, 25, 5);
      gbl.setConstraints(Start, gbc);
      panel.add(Start);

      gbc.gridx = 15;
      gbc.gridy = 11;
      gbc.gridwidth = 5;
      gbc.gridheight = 5;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(25, 5, 25, 5);
      gbl.setConstraints(Stop, gbc);
      panel.add(Stop);

      gbc.gridx = 10;
      gbc.gridy = 4;
      gbc.gridwidth = 10;
      gbc.gridheight = 7;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(35, 5, 40, 5);
      gbl.setConstraints(Configure, gbc);
      panel.add(Configure);

      gbc.gridx = 10;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.gridwidth = 10;
      gbc.gridheight = 4;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(25, 5, 20, 5);
      gbl.setConstraints(AddRecipiants, gbc);
      panel.add(AddRecipiants);

      Progress.setMaximum(100);
      Progress.setString("0%");
      Progress.setValue(0);
      gbc.gridx = 10;
      gbc.gridy = 16;
      gbc.gridwidth = 10;
      gbc.gridheight = 4;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(25, 5, 15, 5);
      gbl.setConstraints(Progress, gbc);
      panel.add(Progress);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.gridwidth = 10;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 45, 0, 45);
      gbl.setConstraints(RLable, gbc);
      panel.add(RLable);

      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ive tried all 3.. compile the code i put, it isnt even in the right area in the first place

Comment: I'm sorry, works fine me, must be something that you're doing